# I18N in a Clean Architecture backend

Tags: internationalization, backend, clean-architecture

I am implementing a backend API that needs to have i18n on the responses, am implementing it using clean architecture, but I can't figure it out where to put the i18n logic in my project.

For me the i18n must be separated from my domain as it has more to do with presentation, but how can I structure a project knowing this upfront?.

If the i18n can't be called within a domain use case, how am I able to do the "business logic" if the queries under it need the language to filter? (am doing database translation tables to store the different languages).

Is it ok to call this "i18n service" in a "controller" class instead of a use case?, or maybe the i18n is in fact part of the domain and there is nothing wrong to call it inside it?.

Comment: Hey! The question is, what is the translated content you are returning from the backend. Is it user defined content. Or are you just translating hard coded messages from the backend? Can you share more information about your specific use case? 

Generally speaking it's not good idea to store i18n strings in database, since you cannot simply take it and send it to translators, but when it it user defined content and users are responsible for translating, then it makes perfect sense.

Comment: Hi!, well my use case is like imagine a table "ONG" with an "ONG_Translation" table, the ONG can have a title and a description which can change according to the requested language (we are not closed in chaging the translation table to a more suitable form, but right now is like that)

Comment: What is ONG and ONG_Translation? Do you change the data from the business logic code or is it just something you manually populate?

Comment: Sorry ONG is the spanish translation for a NGO (literally a non profit org), so the table has information about it, and the translations had anything in the ngo that might get translated into another language (like its description and title). Right now it can be populated from code, and be fetched by language too

Comment: Well, I still don't have enough information about the project, but so far it seems like the content is indeed "user defined content" and in this case your approach is correct and it's OK to treat it as a part of the domain. I recently wrote an article about some pitfalls of implementing custom i18n solution: https://tolgee.io/blog/dont-create-your-own-i18n-library . If something covered there is your case, then it's maybe time to reconsider your approach. 